# Wordpress Mediaupload is empty

Tags: wordpress, plugins

So i am creating a wordpress custom block plugin, here i have 1 block with multiple mediaupload's

the first one works 100%, when i want to add an image this shows up:[image]
but when i try to upload an image from the second or third media upload this is empty:[image]

the code:

```
     html: false,
        // Turn off reusable block feature
        reusable: false,
        // Add alignwide and alignfull options
        align: false
    },
    attributes: {
        image: {
            type: 'object',
            selector: 'grid-wide-4-logo-1'
        },
        image2: {
            type: 'object',
            selector: 'grid-wide-4-logo-2'
        },
       
     

    },

    edit: props => {

        const { attributes, className, setAttributes } = props
        const { image, image2, image3 } = attributes
        return (
            <div class="grid-wide-4-block">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <MediaUploadCheck>
                            <MediaUpload
                                className="grid-wide-4-logo-1"
                                allowedTypes={['image']}
                                multiple={false}
                                value={image ? image.id : ''}
                                onSelect={image => setAttributes({ image: image })}
                                render={({ open }) => (
                                    image ?
                                        <div>
                                            <p >
                                                <img src={image.url} class="grid-wide-4-logo-1" />
                                            </p>

                                            <p>
                                                <Button onClick={() => setAttributes({ image: '' })} className="button is-small">Remove</Button>
                                            </p>
                                        </div> :
                                        <Button onClick={open} className="button">Upload Image</Button>
                                )}
                            />
                        </MediaUploadCheck>
                    </div>

                    <div>
//this mediaupload shows empty
                        <MediaUploadCheck>
                            <MediaUpload
                                className="grid-wide-4-logo-2"
                                allowedTypes={['image2']}
                                multiple={false}
                                value={image2 ? image2.id : ''}
                                onSelect={image2 => setAttributes({ image2: image2 })}
                                render={({ open }) => (
                                    image2 ?
                                        <div>
                                            <p>
                                                <img src={image2.url} class="grid-wide-4-logo-2" />
                                            </p>

                                            <p>
                                                <Button onClick={() => setAttributes({ image2: '' })} className="button is-small">Remove</Button>
                                            </p>
                                        </div> :
                                        <Button onClick={open} className="button">Upload Image</Button>
                                )}
                            />
                        </MediaUploadCheck>
                      
                    </div>
```

is there any explanation why the second mediaupload is not working correctly?
i can upload and image and it will load in, but i cannot see the image directory from it

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
allowedTypes={['image2']}
```

to

```
allowedTypes={['image']}
```